# Is it possible to become less reliant on emotional reasoning?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, therapy

This [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/evolution-the-self/201706/what-s-emotional-reasoning-and-why-is-it-such-problem) in Psychology Today discusses problems associated with '*emotional reasoning*'.  The article also proposes the use of several psychological therapies intended to overcome and/or reduce the impact of *emotional reasoning*.

Questions:

1. Is *emotional reasoning* a real thing?
2. Are the proposed therapies efficacious for mitigating the negative aspects of *emotional reasoning*?
3. Is it possible to change someone’s beliefs without using counter-emotional tactics (i.e. generate a counter emotion to change the person's belief)?

Comment: Related: [Why do humans need emotions?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9647/7001), [Is there any actual evidence for the common model of the “real you” and a separate section that contains all your weaknesses?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26007/7001), [Does fixing cognitive biases do more harm than use?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8596/7001)